# Corel Draw for Mac on Linux

Tags: wine

Several years ago I stopped trying to ger Corel Draw to work on Linux with Wine, but recenttly they reintroduced a Mac version. I saw that someone tried to run the 2020 Windows version but what about Mac? The reason I ask is Mac and Linux both have a Unixish OS. Anyone pursuing this?

Comment: Although Mac and GNU/Linux have many similarities with UNIX, they are usually not binary compatible. While I don't know how to answer your question, but did you try Inkscape? It may not have all functionalities of Corel Draw, but it is a good (and free) alternative for basic tasks.

Comment: Using both Corel and Inkscape I strongly disagree. Inkscape is completely vector (svg) based and its UI not intuitive. Corel Draw is much more user friendly and takes a complete different approach how to get pictures done... I've let it run in a stripped down Windows VM

Comment: Did a bit of googling since was curious if anything like wine was for mac programs.  Found this, do not know if it is any good.  Seems to be recent/up to date.  https://ostechnix.com/run-macos-software-on-linux-using-darling/